# Bash: subtracting 10 mins from a given time

Tags: bash, time

In a bash script, if I have a number that represents a time, in the form hhmmss (or hmmss), what is the best way of subtracting 10 minutes?

ie, 90000 -> 85000

Answer (score 25):

This is a bit tricky. Date can do general manipulations, i.e. you can do:

```
date --date '-10 min'
```

Specifying hour-min-seconds (using UTC because otherwise it seems to assume PM):

```
date --date '11:45:30 UTC -10 min'
```

To split your date string, the only way I can think of is substring expansion:

```
a=114530
date --date "${a:0:2}:${a:2:2}:${a:4:2} UTC -10 min"
```

And if you want to just get back hhmmss:

```
date +%H%M%S --date "${a:0:2}:${a:2:2}:${a:4:2} UTC -10 min"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So to clarify...the time is not the present time...it is a five or six digit number passed into the script as a parameter...would this approach work for this?

Comment: @RogerMoore yes, that's why I use --date. It has to be written as "hh:mm:ss UTC" because otherwise date won't be able to misinterpret it, but it seemed to work for your purpose. I'm not sure what happens when you pass in a time in the form of hh:mm:s, you best test it, also around midnight and noon.

Answer (score 5):

why not just use epoch time and then take 600 off of it?

```
$ echo "`date +%s` - 600"| bc; date 
1284050588
Thu Sep  9 11:53:08 CDT 2010
$ date -d '1970-01-01 UTC 1284050588 seconds' +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"
2010-09-09 11:43:08 -0500
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is I don't require to do it based on the present time.  It is an arbitrary time will be passed into the script as a five or six digit number.

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to strip your own styling/features and use a conventional prompt like "$" when posting.  (I set `PS1='\$ '` before answering these questions so I can still copy-paste.)

Comment: I would just modernize the 1st line as `echo "$(( $(date +%s) - 600))"; date`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a 5 *or* 6 digit number, you have to pad it before doing string manipulation:

```
$ t=90100
$ while [ ${#t} -lt 6 ]; do t=0$t; done
$ echo $t
090100
$ date +%H%M%S --utc -d"today ${t:0:2}:${t:2:2}:${t:4:2} UTC - 10 minutes"
085100
```

Note both --utc and UTC are required to make sure the system's timezone doesn't affect the results.

For math within bash (i.e. `$((` and `((`), leading zeros will cause the number to be interpreted as octal.  However, your data is more string-like (with a special format) than number-like, anyway.  I've used a while loop above because it sounds like you're treating it as a number and thus might get 100 for 12:01 am.

Answer (score 1):

My version of bash doesn't support -d or --date as used above. However, assuming a correctly 0-padded input, this does work

```
$ input_time=130503 # meaning "1:05:03 PM"

# next line calculates epoch seconds for today's date at stated time
$ epoch_seconds=$(date -jf '%H%M%S' $input_time '+%s')

# the 600 matches the OP's "subtract 10 minutes" spec. Note: Still relative to "today"
$ calculated_seconds=$(( epoch_seconds - 600 )) # bc would work here but $((...)) is builtin

# +%H%M%S formats the result same as input, but you can do what you like here
$ echo $(date -r $calculated_seconds '+%H%M%S')

# output is 125503: Note that the hour rolled back as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

For **MacOS users** you can do the following:

```
$(date -v -10M +"%H:%M:%S")
```

Date time without a specific format:

```
$(date -v -10M)
```

For **non-macOS** users:

Date time without a specific format:

```
date --date '-10 min'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
date +%H%M%S -d "- 10 min"
```

is ok for me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?