# How to subtract minutes from a given time?

Tags: linux, date, ubuntu

I have a given time string `14:00` and want to subtract 5 Minutes.
How can this be done in bash?

Gives me a datetime object: `date -d "14:00" +'%H:%M'` -> `14:00`

I tried subtract: `date -d "14:00 - 5min" +'%H:%M'` 
-> Gives `21:01`. But Why?

Desired result if of course: `13:55`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675326/bash-subtracting-10-mins-from-a-given-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
$ date -d "14:00 5 minutes ago" +'%H:%M'
13:55
```

I can't explain why though.

Answer (score 0):

From the info page for gnu date:

```
     Our units of temporal measurement, from seconds on up to months,
     are so complicated, asymmetrical and disjunctive so as to make
     coherent mental reckoning in time all but impossible.  Indeed, had
     some tyrannical god contrived to enslave our minds to time, to make
     it all but impossible for us to escape subjection to sodden
     routines and unpleasant surprises, he could hardly have done better
     than handing down our present system.  It is like a set of
     trapezoidal building blocks, with no vertical or horizontal
     surfaces, like a language in which the simplest thought demands
     ornate constructions, useless particles and lengthy
     circumlocutions.  Unlike the more successful patterns of language
     and science, which enable us to face experience boldly or at least
     level-headedly, our system of temporal calculation silently and
     persistently encourages our terror of time.

—Robert Grudin, ‘Time and the Art of Living’.
```

.

and, more relevantly:

```
The time may alternatively be followed by a time zone correction,
expressed as ‘SHHMM’, where S is ‘+’ or ‘-’, HH is a number of zone
hours and MM is a number of zone minutes
```

Your attempt to perform arithmetic is failing, and date is trying to parse the expression "- 5min" as a time zone correction.